# What is the switchIfEmpty alternative in Smallrye Mutiny

Tags: reactive-programming, quarkus, reactive-streams, smallrye

In RxJava 2 and Reactor there is a `switchIfEmpty`like method to switch to new flow if there is no elements in current flow.

But when I began to use [Minuty](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny), I can not find an alternative when I convert my Quarkus sample to use the Reactive features.

Currently my solution is: in my [`PostRepository`](https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sample/blob/master/mutiny/src/main/java/com/example/PostRepository.java#L40-L45),  I use an exception to indicate there is no post found.

```java
 public Uni<Post> findById(UUID id) {
        return this.client
                .preparedQuery("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=$1", Tuple.of(id))
                .map(RowSet::iterator)
                .flatMap(it -> it.hasNext() ? Uni.createFrom().item(rowToPost(it.next())) : Uni.createFrom().failure(()-> new PostNotFoundException()));
    }
```

And catch it in the [`PostResource`](https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sample/blob/master/mutiny/src/main/java/com/example/PostResource.java#L45-L52).

```java
@Path("{id}")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Uni<Response> getPostById(@PathParam("id") final String id) {
        return this.posts.findById(UUID.fromString(id))
                .map(data -> ok(data).build())
                .onFailure(PostNotFoundException.class).recoverWithItem(status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build());
    }
```

How to return an `Uni` means 0 or 1 element in `PostRepository`, and use a `switchIfEmpty` like method in `PostResource` to build the alternative path for the flow?

Answer (score 4):

`Uni` cannot be *empty* in the sense it always contains an item (potentially `null`).

So, the equivalent of `switchIfEmpty` is `uni.onItem().ifNull().switchTo(() -> ...)`

Comment: It does not work as `switchIfEmpty` in the stream if there is null.The `null` is still passed to the main flow, eg `map(null will go here instead).onItem().ifNull...`.

Comment: Yes, because `null` is a valid item as it's part of the Java language. We have added `ifNonNull` in Mutiny 0.5.0.

Comment: Mutiny 2.5.6 has an `Uni.creatyFrom().nothing();` is that an empty Uni?
In project-reactor Mono couldn't have a null, but it could be empty, in Mutiny we should use a Uni with null item as the empty Uni? And use the above way to check it?
Why a Uni can't be empty? It feel intuitive i think to be allowed to be empty. Also Uni doesn't have a onComplete which confuses me, but i guess its the same as onItem.

Comment: There is a distinction between a Uni never emitting an item or a failure, and an Uni emitting `null`. Mono.empty would be equivalent to a Uni emitting `null`.